# Spring Data LDAP using Pageable is it possible?

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl, spring-ldap

I use spring Data LDAP, I want return all user but by page. `findAll` work but return all user.

I try user `Page<UserLdap> findAll(Pageable pageable);` but I have tise error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'userLdapRepository':
Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException:
No property findAll found for type UserLdap!
```

full code:

```
public interface UserLdapRepository extends LdapRepository<UserLdap> {
    Set<UserLdap> findAll();
    Page<UserLdap> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I try add `extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserLdap, Name>` but I have the same error.

full code:

```
public interface UserLdapRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserLdap, Name>, LdapRepository<UserLdap> {
    Set<UserLdap> findAll();
    Page<UserLdap> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Is it possible using Pageable with Spring Data LDAP please?**

**EDIT:**

I find this code in Spring Data ldap:

```
public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) { ...
```

What is it a predicate please? If you have a sample, I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible:

**UnsupportedOperationException()**

```
@Override
public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Due to specifics of the LDAP protocol, paging and sorting are not supported for Spring LDAP repositories."

See more in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/current/reference/html/#ldap.repositories